# How to use Regex to match PHP time() or microtime() in a string?

Tags: php, regex, time, microtime

I currently have a regex command which matches php time in a string:

```
preg_match( '/([a-z]+)_([0-9]{9,})\.jpg/i', $aName, $lMatches );
```

How can I modify this to also match microtime() in the same match?

Examples:

foobar_1453887550.jpg (match)

foobar_1453887620.8717.jpg (match)

foobar_123.jpg (don't match)

foobar_adsf123123.jpg (don't match)

Comment: provide some examples..

Comment: @AvinashRaj examples provided

Comment: time start from which date? 19700101 ok?

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/qS3rM9/1

Comment: ([a-z]+)_([0-9]{9,})(\.[0-9]{1,}){0,1}\.jpg

Comment: I think using named captures can be of help here, use `(?<f>[a-z]+)_(?<t>\d{9,})(?:\.(?<m>\d+))?\.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add optional group using `?`:

```
preg_match( '/([a-z]+)_([0-9]{9,})(\.[0-9]{4,})?\.jpg/i', $aName, $lMatches );
```

Here `(\.[0-9]{4,})?` is an optional group which can present or not in your string.

Considering @trincot remark you can change optional group to `(\.[0-9]+)?` if ending zeroes will not present in milliseconds.

```
preg_match( '/([a-z]+)_([0-9]{9,})(\.[0-9]+)?\.jpg/i', $aName, $lMatches );
```

Comment: I would not assume the decimal part must consist of 4 digits. If there are ending zeroes they would not be included.

Comment: @trincot How's then - `{1,4}`?

Comment: If indeed microtime has at the most 4 decimals, that would be it, but it is not clear from the OP what are the limits. I would just use `+`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your regex above shouldn't match the second example: *foobar_1453887620.8717.jpg*

Now if you want it to match a number of digits less than 9, after the '_' , you need to modify the `{9,}` as needed.

`{9,}` matches the prior match (in this case a digit `[0-9]`), repeated nine times or above.

- To include your second example(*foobar_1453887620.8717.jpg*) in the
  match, your regex should be:
  `/([a-z]+)_([0-9.]{9,})\.jpg/i`
- To match your third example (foobar_123.jpg):
  `/([a-z]+)_([0-9]{3,})\.jpg/i`
- To match your fourth example (foobar_adsf123123.jpg):
  `/([a-z]+)_([0-9\w]{3,})\.jpg/i`
- To match all your examples above:
  `/([a-z]+)_([0-9.\w]{3,})\.jpg/i`